# Geting multiple return value from PyObject in C#

Tags: c#, python

I wrote the following code to execute python script using Python.Runtime. It succeed if my python method has a single return value. How can I get multiple return values from PyObject if my python method actually return multiple values?

```
using (Py.GIL())
            {
                dynamic test = Py.Import("test");
                PyObject ob2 = test.test_method();
                string str2 = ob2.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(str2);
            }
```

my test.py is like this:

```
def test_method():
   x = 1
   y = "name"
   return x,y
```

If my test_method() only return x, or only return y, my code has no problem. However, if I want to separately get the value of x and y in my C# code. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found that I just need to use

```
string str2 = ob2.GetItem(0).ToString();
```

to get different values.